# NDB query against multiple kinds

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is it possible to query against multiple kinds (I am using NDB models) with one query?

I am trying to build a forum-like message feed where you can post a normal forum type comment, but also other things like photos, polls, etc.

I would have all these feed items belong to a common ancestor (the page they belong to) and query against that, but I believe that would greatly limit the write throughput.

So I need to be able to query all of the page's feed items in one query, and would like to use separate models (if possible). I can make some fake models within the app to achieve this (and use just one gae kind for all types), but was wondering if anyone had any other ideas.

Thank you very much

Comment: In addition to polymodels, you can do kindless ancestor queries.  But thats it.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Kindless_Ancestor_Queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`PolyModel`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/polymodelclass) class:

> The PolyModel class is the superclass for data model definitions that
>   can themselves be superclasses for other data model definitions. A
>   query produced from a PolyModel class can have results that are
>   instances of the class or any of its subclasses.

Comment: Thanks this worked out very well. One slightly annoying side effect is all subtypes end up as PolyModel in the data store viewer, but all else works very well.

Comment: @warren You're welcome... I'm not sure if you can do much about that.. but the good news are that the end user don't have to see that.. so as long as it solves the problem in a proper/desired way you're good to go!